# C# MongoDB Timeseries bulk update with duplicate records upsert

Tags: c#, mongodb, time-series

Using MongoDB 7 and MongoDB.Driver 2.24.0 in .NET 7

I have a MongoDB collection that is defined as a Timeseries, works fine if I only do insertions, but now, the records can come duplicate and I have to do some kind of insert/update. I've searched some examples of upserts but seem to play wrong with time series , so I ended doing it like this

cTimeseries is a simple C# class like this

```
public class Ctimeseries {
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Date in format "2024-03-12T14:14:57.000Z"
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }// = new (0,0);
    /// <summary>
    /// string with an alfanumeric code
    /// </summary>
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; } = new Metadata();
    /// <summary>
    /// set of 8 measurements
    /// </summary>
    public double[] Measurements { get; set; } 
    /// <summary>
    /// Summer Flag
    /// </summary>
    public byte Summer { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// kind of measure, default 1
    /// </summary>
    public byte MeasureKind { get; set; } = 1;
    /// <summary>
    /// extra data 26 caracters
    /// </summary>
    public string Extradata { get; set; }
}
```

And my current upsert implementation is this

```
 public async Task Upsert(List<Ctimeseries> records)
 {
     //queue all the deletes from incoming records and bulk delete/insert
     List<DeleteOneModel<Ctimeseries>> requests = new List<DeleteOneModel<Ctimeseries>>(records.Count());
     foreach (Ctimeseries record in records) {
         var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Ctimeseries>().Where(m => m.timestamp == record.timestamp && m.metadata == record.metadata);
         var request = new DeleteOneModel<Ctimeseries>(filter); //queue the delete
         requests.Add(request);
     }
     await _CtimeseriesCol.BulkWriteAsync(requests); //perform bulk delete <- "flowControl": {"acquireCount": 2232},"durationMillis": 3748    1,67921146953405 ms per record
     await _CtimeseriesCol.InsertManyAsync(records); //perform bulk insert <- "flowControl": {"acquireCount": 54133},"durationMillis": 92724  1,712892320765522 ms per record
 }
```

This numbers are not so great. With pure insertmayasync I inserted 9M records in about 5 minutes. With this, after 1h, I'm a little over 1M inserts.

Am I doing extra work here? Should I create Bson documents to call the c# driver in another way?

First I created the insertmany and worked like a dream. After that, tried the example in [MongoDb C# driver - upsert many based on "candidate" key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543056/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-upsert-many-based-on-candidate-key)
but got
A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors. WriteErrors: [ { Category : "Uncategorized", Code : 72, Message : "Cannot perform a non-multi update on a time-series collection" } ].

Best regards.

Comment: The options you have with time series collections in that respect are limited. Maybe you can detect duplicates before inserting e.g. by storing the last timestamp for a combination of meta-data in another collection. Then you can remove older entries before the `InsertMany`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @markus has commented , there is currently no way to do this with timeseries, so I'm going back to normal collections and add a version flag.